# How do I set an onClick on a page in ViewPager?

Tags: android

I have an issue when I use onClick in a LinearLayout of a fragment layout that is displayed in a ViewPager. I want the keyboard to come up on my EditText when tapping on the LinearLayout.

However, I have noticed that even though the LinearLayout's width and height are set to match_parent it will not fit the whole page in the ViewPager, not allowing a user to click anywhere within the page to bring up the keyboard. I also tried setting an onClick to the ViewPager, but the click event was not registering.

I have spent much time trying to figure out a solution and will greatly appreciate any help on how I can overcome this problem.

I am using DataBinding in my code.

Here is the XML code for the layout of the fragment being displayed in the ViewPager:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 
 <layout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
 
     <data>
 
         <variable
 name="entryPageFragmentClickHandler"   type="com.example.scriber_writecustomizeshare.fragments.entry_page_fragment_mvc.EntryPageFragmentImplementationMVC.EntryPageFragmentClickHandler" />
 
         <variable
 name="entryPage"
 type="com.example.scriber_writecustomizeshare.models.EntryPage" />
 
     </data>
 
     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/fragmentEntryPageLinearLayout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:focusable="true"
 android:onClick="@{entryPageFragmentClickHandler::showAndHideKeyboard}">
 
         <EditText
 android:id="@+id/fragmentEntryPageEditText"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_margin="8dp"
 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
 android:text="@{entryPage.pageText}"
 android:textSize="15sp"
 android:onClick="@{entryPageFragmentClickHandler::showAndHideKeyboard}" />
 
     </LinearLayout>
 
 </layout>
```

Also, here is the XML code of the activity layout with the ViewPager:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layout
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

     <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
         android:id="@+id/activityCreateNewDrawerLayout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

         <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
             android:id="@+id/fragmentEntryPageCoordinatorLayout"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".activities.EditEntryActivity">

             <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                 android:id="@+id/fragmentEntryPageAppBar"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                 android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                 <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                     app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|exitUntilCollapsed">

                     <LinearLayout
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:orientation="horizontal"
                         android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
                         app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                         app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7">

                         <Button
                             android:id="@+id/addBulletPointsButton"
                             android:layout_width="100dp"
                             android:layout_height="45dp"
                             android:text="Bullet" />

                         <Button
                             android:id="@+id/indentButton"
                             android:layout_width="100dp"
                             android:layout_height="45dp"
                             android:text="Indent" />

                     </LinearLayout>

                     <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                         android:id="@+id/editEntryPageToolbar"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                         app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                         app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

                 </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

             </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

             <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                 android:id="@+id/fragmentEntryPageNestedScrollView"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:layout_margin="8dp"
                  app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

                 <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                     android:id="@+id/entryPageViewPager"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent" />

             </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

         </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

         <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
             android:id="@+id/activityCreateNewNavigationView"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_gravity="end"
             app:menu="@menu/activity_create_new_navigation_menu" />

     </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

 </layout>
```